# Unmarshaling irregular JSON file

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have a problem with unmarshaling JSON response from one of the APIs. API returns an array of simple objects. It has a structure:

```
  "dataFields": [
    {
      "key": "Example_key1",
      "value": "Example_value3"
    },
    {
      "key": "Example_key2",
      "value": "Example_value3"
    },
    {
      "key": "Example_key3",
      "value": "Example_value3"
    }
  ]
```

Generally, there are always 2 strings (possibly a null instead of a string, but this is not a problem).

Unfortunately, recently the provider has introduced a new field that looks like this:

```
{
  "key": "Example_key4",
  "value": false
}
```

Now I can not unpack it to a simple unmarshal to the structure I used before:

```
type DataField struct {
Value string `json:"value,omitempty"`
Key   string `json:"key,omitempty"`
}
```

Can you suggest to me how you can unpack something like that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could change the type of your `Value` field to `interface{}` and type switch on it. "How to handle it" kind of depends on *what* you're actually doing with it.

Comment: I collect this data and analyze it and place it in the database

Comment: "collect, analyze and store" isn't a useful description.

Comment: See [the example for json.RawMessage](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_RawMessage_unmarshal) for how to parse Value depending on Key.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/yt49VCr2TBY

Comment: Does the type of the value depend on the key?  For example, is the value for Example_Key4 always a bool?  If so, see [Decoding Generic JSON Objects to One of Many Formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033277/golang-decoding-generic-json-objects-to-one-of-many-formats).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved using the structure:

```
type DataField struct {
Value interface{} `json:"value,omitempty"`
Key   string      `json:"key,omitempty"`
}
```