# Golang websocket server: handling unknown JSON data structure

Tags: json, go, websocket, gorilla

I am having some trouble handling data received by my websocket server written in Go using gorilla.
I am communicating in JSON, where there is a action_type to every JSON object, but rest of the content is unknown at run time. I currently use `conn.ReadJSON(&message)` where `message := make(map[string]interface{})`. The problem is when the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "action_type": "test",
  "something": {
    "one": 1,
    "two": "two",
  },
}
```

How would I go about parsing "something" in to Go variable with defined Go struct:

```
type Something struct {
  one  int
  two  string
}
```

`s := data["something"].(Something)` is not working, returning error: *interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not Something*.

Comment: Use json.RawMessage to capture the varying part of the message. See [Decoding generic JSON objects to one of many formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033277/decoding-generic-json-objects-to-one-of-many-formats) for a complete explanation.

Comment: Thanks! 'Decoding generic JSON objects to one of many formats' solved my question excellently.